# DateTime picket in Sencha touch using architect

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am trying to import the date Time component available in sencha market into my architect (Sencha touch 2.3 and architect 3) project but not able to do so. 
The component is [here](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/datetimepicker)

I tried creating AUX file out of it using the tutorial given in sencha website but when I try to use the new extension I get the error:-

> "Cannot call method **substring** of undefined"

Did any one tried to import this component in sencha? If yes can you share the aux file or is there any other way to get dateTime in sencha touch

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it my self with some RnD.
Attaching the aux file for future reference
[Download Aux](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44602273/DateTimePicker.aux)